# Abort an (accidental and old/dangling) rebase but keep all changes

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am working locally on a branch (master). I previously made a rebase to squash some commits which I thought worked. I continued to make a number of commits until I needed to perform another rebase. When I called `git rebase -i HEAD~3` I got the error:

> Interactive rebase already started

suggesting that I never properly finished the old rebase.

Now I want to abort the old rebase, without losing any of my changes since it began. I was going to use

```
git rebase --abort
```

but I'm pretty sure that will remove all my local commits and put be back before the rebase. What can I do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commit them. Abort the rebase. Pull the commit from `git reflog`.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Rebased changes"
git rebase --abort
git cherry-pick HEAD@{1}
```

Do with it what you will. If your `git reflog` expired (I can't imagine a situation where this would occur in normal day-to-day operations), cut a new branch then abort the rebase:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Rebase changes"
git checkout -b rebased-master
git rebase --abort
```

Comment: I think this is nearly what I need, but regarding the first approach, will `cherry-pick` only pull a single commit back or will it pull all the preceding commits from when I started the faulty rebase to when I aborted it? I need the latter, i.e. all of them.

Comment: Ok, I seemed to have sorted this. I checked `git reflog` after aborting the rebase and found the commit I wanted to restore back to and did a `git reset --hard XXXXXX`